# nested Shortcode doesn't work

Tags: shortcode

Shortcode:

```
[permalink][title][/permalink]
```

Output:

```
<a href="foobar">[title]</a>
```

Wordpress shortcode API sais, it's correct:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the page you linked:

> The shortcode parser correctly deals
>   with nested shortcode macros, provided
>   their handler functions support it by
>   recursively calling do_shortcode():

You need to recursively call `do_shortcode()` on any shortcode handler that could contain nested shortcodes. So for example:

```
function wpse18659_permalink( $atts, $content ){
    return '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="Permalink to ' . get_the_title() . '" alt="">' . do_shortcode( $content ) . '</a>';
}

add_shortcode( 'permalink', 'wpse18659_permalink' );
```

That should handle nested shortcodes just fine.

Comment: This one will help me a lot! Upvoted ;)